# returning back from displayed image in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am displaying html string in webview, content includes an image also. Tapping on the image opens the image in whole webview (covering the whole webview ). I am not able to return back to the main content. How can i return back ? n yeah, i have used UIWebview delegate method goBack also, but nothing happens.

Comment: How is the image opened fully? Link / javascript?

Comment: @Wain: image opened using link.

Comment: So back should work. What is returned by canGoBack and how is the delegate involved when you try (you tried calling goBack from a delegate method?).

Comment: canGoBack returns NO. And i am calling goBack from my own method on back button click, not from a delegate method.

Comment: canGoBack returning no basically means that the image wasn't shown by a link. Or, by link do you really mean you're detecting the link press in a delegate method and showing the image in another view over the web view. How about adding a little code...

Comment: actually, i am displaying whole HTML string in webview. Image source basically is the <img> tag containing the external link as source.

Comment: [myWebView loadHTMLString:stringHtml baseURL:nil];